# Is it posible to preserve website bindings when deploying using Octopus?

Tags: deployment, web-deployment, continuous-deployment, octopus-deploy

Octopus clears the bindings each time it deploys the website.
I found this aswers on Octopus's forum but it is outdated (2018) and I could not find anything regarding new updates:

https://help.octopus.com/t/preserving-website-bindings-when-using-deploy-to-iis-step/20865

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the "Merge with existing bindings" option on the IIS deployment step?

[image]